# javascript .replace() keeping part of the evalueted string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

what i need to do is look inside a string for something like "12345" and replace it with 12345 so basically search for any number within quotes and replace it with just the number without the quotes.

I've tried something but i don't know how to keep the evalueted number removing only the quotes.

Some examples:

foo bar "123" bar --> foo bar 123 bar

foo bar "123qwe" bar --> foo bar "123qwe" bar

foo "bar" "123" bar --> foo "bar" 123 bar

Thank you in advance.

Solved:

```
.replace(/"([0-9]+)"/g, '$1');
```

Comment: Please show the code you have written to solve the problem.

Comment: typo, where i said brackets i obviously meant quotes

Comment: @LeoBalzoni you can always edit your question if you find typos or to include further information. Just use the edit-button right below the tags.

Comment: it actually was not a duplicate but thanks for the advices, this was my first question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex should work for you `"([0-9]+)"` :

```js
var s = 'test "test" 123 "123" ""';
s = s.replace(/"([0-9]+)"/g, "$1");
console.log(s);
```

Comment: thanks! this works!

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```js
function getResult(str){
    console.log(str.replace(/"(\d+)"/g, '$1'));
}

getResult('foo bar "123" bar');

getResult('foo bar "123qwe" bar');

getResult('foo "bar" "123" bar');
```